# Microsoft Access search for multiple emails

Tags: sql, email, ms-access, select

In Access when I query the contact table to search for multiple email addresses I use the SQL

```
 select * from contact_table where email like " 'email1@test.com','email2@test.com',
'email3@test.com'  "
```

I do not get an error however I get no search results when I know the emails are in the database, what am I missing?

Also is this the best way to query a lookup table of email addresses in Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you should be using the `in` operator, not the `like` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   contact_table 
WHERE  email IN ('email1@test.com',
                 'email2@test.com',
                 'email3@test.com')
```